# Homology of knot complement with Mayer Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory

I would like to find a **completely algebraic** argument to the fact that the second homology group of a knot complement is trivial.

Concretely, let $K$ be a knot and let $V$ be a tubular neighbourhood of $K$ homeomorphic to the solid torus, and let $X:= \overline{S^3 - V}$ the knot complement. Using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence with the cover $U_1 := V$, $U_2:=X$ of $S^3$,  we obtain the exact sequence

$$0 \to H_3 (S^3) = \mathbb{Z} \overset{\delta}{\to} \mathbb{Z}=H_2 (S^1 \times S^1) \to H_2 (X) \to 0  .$$

I want to find an algebraic argument (that is, avoiding sketchy arguments involving simplices like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028054/boundary-map-in-mayer-vietoris-and-homology-of-knot-complement)) of the fact that the connecting homomorphism is an isomorphism. I tried to argue with the naturality of the long exact sequence, but with no success so far.

Comment: Alexander  duality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know that the statement is trivial using Alexander Duality, but I wanted to show this using Mayer-Vietoris. Any idea?

Comment: Page 12 of "An Introduction to Knot Theory" by Raymond Lickorish has the answer. The argument is simplicial, but it doesn't require you to subdivide or anything like that. All you need is a triangulation of $S^3$ that is fine enough so that $V$ and $S^3-V$ are subcomplexes.

Comment: @Prototank I was also following this book, and I am afraid that is precisely the argument that I want to avoid.

Comment: What is sketchy about the argument?

Comment: @Prototank In the book, 3rd paragraph of the proof, he simply describes what the connecting homomorphism does, concluding with "inspection of the map (...) shows that a generator is sent to a generator, so it is an isomorphism". Let me say that those lines are quite void.

Comment: While you can deduce what the connecting homomorphism does from that paragraph, if you look carefully he actually is telling you explicitly how the generator of $H_3(S^3)$ is sent to the generator of $H_2(X\cap N)$. Since both of these modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, this means that the connecting map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Zach Haney uses a different Mayer-Vietoris-argument (which does not use any simplicial agurments) in Proposition 1.5 of his [lecture notes](https://web.northeastern.edu/beasley/MATH7375/Lecture4.pdf).

Comment: @TimoE. Thanks, I think I can walk away with that - although this is a strong result, it implies Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the rules of this platform, but should I make my comment into an answer?